Overwrite notation in LEAN4
As a pedagogical project, I am trying to reinvent the wheel in LEAN4 and create my own versions of some mathematics areas.
This means that I have a lot of name collisions with the original library, which I can avoid easily by creating a custom namespace. However, there is one thing I haven't been able to figure out how to do, which is overwriting existing notation.
As an example, if I define a new notation as
notation:max "¬" p:40 => Custom.Not p

then I cannot use it anywhere since it always gives the error
ambiguous, possible interpretations 
  ¬P : Prop
  
  ¬P : Prop

where one refers to Custom.Not and the other to Not or _root_.Not. It doesn't matter whether I define this notation inside the Custom namespace or not; I cannot work with it.
Of course I can write things as Not P, which is what I have been doing, but it is starting to be quite inconvenient.
Is there anyway I can overwrite the existing notation?

I think overloading notation for Prop is  difficult or impossible.  Using a different symbol is the easiest solution.  A more difficult solution would be to put prelude at the top of your file (before the imports).  This would be as close to a blank slate as you could get.  You would then get to manually select exactly what files from Init to import or reimplement.  (Init is typically imported automatically and includes things like logical notation.)

You can increase the priority of your notation:
def Custom.Not p := p → False

notation:max (priority := high) "¬" p:40 => Custom.Not p

set_option pp.notation false
#check ¬False
-- Custom.Not False : Prop


Thanks! This indeed seams to be the perfect solution to my problem.
